# Difference between client.query and Table.query in Dynamodb

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

What is the difference between client.query and Table.query

In which case client.query should be get privilege over Table.query and vice versa

On AWS documentation I came across few points one of them

**If the total number of items meeting the query criteria exceeds the result set size limit of 1 MB, the query stops and results are returned to the user with the LastEvaluatedKey element to continue the query in a subsequent operation. Unlike a Scan operation, a Query operation never returns both an empty result set and a LastEvaluatedKey value. LastEvaluatedKey is only provided if the results exceed 1 MB, or if you have used the Limit parameter.**

But i didn't find the same for table.query, also I am not able to get LastEvaluatedKey  property in table.query method

Few more things are there but not summarized at one place.

Could i get any link or any stuff to understand difference between them

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

AWS SDK for .NET has multiple APIs for contacting DynamoDB. These are discussed in [this blog post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx17SQHVEMW8MXC/). In short, though, both *client.Query* and *Table.Query* perform a query against a particular table in DynamoDB, but the latter returns Document objects that are easier to work with. *Table.Query* also performs the pagination for you, so you don't have to care about *LastEvaluatedKey*.

You can find more information in the [DynamoDB Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html), including the section on [high-level interfaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ORM.html).

If you have further questions, feel free to post to the [.NET SDK Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=61) or the [DynamoDB forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131).

Comment: I really appreciated the blog post you linked! Thanks!